# Android complains of different com.android.support versions

Tags: android

I am using API 28 for `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` and version and 28.0.0 for support libraries (appcompat and support) in the gradle file of a library module. I don't see any other version like 27 or 21 anywhere in the file. However, Android complains that `All com.android.support must use the same version specification. Found versions 28.0.0, 21.0.3`. I want to know what causes this error? Is there any other library used behind the scenes with a different version I'm unaware of? How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You should post your app level gradle file in this case.

However, you can find the issue by running `./gradlew :app:dependencies` command in terminal to find the culprit. This command will generate transitive dependency tree and you may know in this way that which dependency brings the lower version library to your application, and `exlude` it.

Comment: Your first command returns `Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
`

Comment: Try running `gradle wrapper`. It seems Gradle wrapper is not configured properly.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are using a dependency that uses older version of support version ,
in order to  find that dependencies you can run `gradle dependencies` task.
and for make the result more readable and beautiful the reporting plugin is useful .to add this plugin add `apply plugin: 'project-report'` in your build.gradle file and run `$ ./gradlew htmlDependencyReport`
 after that HTML formatted report is fund in this pass `build/reports/project/dependencies/index.html`

after finding that dependency you can `exclude` like bellow :

```
implementation ('your conflict library') {
exclude "com.android.support"  }
```

Comment: OMG, the resulting report is a huge nightmare full of libraries!

Comment: yes you can make it beautiful and  readable with project-report .do you use it ?